# DAX Cumulative SUM ignores my filter

Tags: excel, powerpivot, excel-2013, dax, cumulative-sum

Essentially I am using two linked tables with PowerPivot. First one contains following columns [Date], [Amount], [Id]. The second table only contains the id's [Id] that are used to filter the first table. This has worked great until I combined this with a measure that calculates a cumulative sum.

```
=CALCULATE(SUM( [Amount] ) ; FILTER(ALL( 'Table') ; 'Table'[Date] <= MAX('Table'[Date] )))
```

I have tried to apply various filters directly into the Calculate-statement, but none of these seem to work. Conditions that should be correct always seem to return an error that the columns can't be determined in the current context. One thing to note is that the [Id] column is a string value.

Optimal solution would be a method for calculating the cumulative value with any Id filters applied to the PivotTable (I use several of these tables to filter to one table with the data), but having multiple variations of the calculated measure is fine too.

I'm new to DAX, so I highly appreciate all the with this!

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired result would be.  Why do you have the filter on the date and the all 'Table' filter? Can you provide an example? Based upon your statement of "calculating the cumulative value with any Id filters applied to the PivotTable" it leads me to believe you just need a calculated measure that is Sum([Amount]), unless there is something specific you are trying to do with the other filters.

Comment: So the idea is to be able to use a time dimension (in another table too, linked to the [Date] column) for filtering the observed data, all while retaining the cumulative sum from the whole period. I can make the measure work by using ALLSELECTED instead of ALL, but I would like to retain the ability to 'pass through' the time filter. The ALLSELECTED does retain the [id] filter as it should, but I would also like to exclude the filter applied to [Date] column @mmarie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. One workaround is to create a new table (i've called it 'Dummy') with just the relevant dates, and created a calculated column in 'Dummy' with the following:

```
=SUMX( FILTER('Table','Table'[Date]<='Dummy'[Date]) , 'Table'[Amount] )
```

After this you should be able to relate 'Table' and 'Dummy' and just pull the cumulative figure from 'Dummy' as you need it.

It's not ideal, and if anyone has a neat formula for obtaining this result without resorting to the creation of an extra table shout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made an error, not in your calculation but in your placement of the equation.

You do not put the calculation in your table, you put on the outside at the bottom.

What you are trying to do is create a pivot table with the dates in the rows and the products on columns, so essentially have running totals for each individual product. If I am not mistaken.

I promise this will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86apl.jpg)